# Electronjs contextBridge main exposition for render not working

Tags: javascript, electron

Hello stackoverflowers,

i'm a bit stuck after coming back to electron after a few years. Im trying to build an app and access the file system with it. I've read that the `remote` is now very disencouraged by electron. To get a list of files from the filesystem, i will need to access the main app from the renderer.

The solution everyone and electron seems to suggest is to use a preload.js with contextBridge to safely expose selected parts you need, which makes sense to me.

However, this is where i'm stuck, i can't seem it to get it to work. I can't really assure that the preload.js is correctly loaded. I've tried to add it the suggested way and even hardcoded the direct path to my file system:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
  },
})
```

The preload.js

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
  send: (channel, data) => {
    let validChannels = ['toMain']
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data)
    }
  },
  receive: (channel, func) => {
    let validChannels = ['fromMain']
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
    }
  },
})
```

however, when i try to access the `window.api` object is undefined and i can't access any retrieval options.

maybe i've missunderstood something, but im stuck here.

EDIT:
I'm using
`"electron": "^12.0.0",`

EDIT2:
i've found it. i was calling electron using the bundled web app instead of my main.js file :facepalm: electron ./public/index.html" of course i needed to call the electron file

Comment: which Electron version do you have? `contextIsolation` is enabled by default only starting from Electron 12

Comment: thanks, i've updated the question. Electron 12

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Are you getting any errors in the dev tools console?

Comment: hmm not at all for the electron app. However i should mention that i use webpack to bundle the webapp. That does should not cause any problems imo though

Comment: ah, i've pointed out that im not sure my preload.js gets loaded at all. Unfortunatelly even hardcoding the whole path does not seem to resolve the problem. I'm on mac os

Comment: i've found it. i was calling electron using the bundled web app instead of my main.js file :facepalm:
`electron ./public/index.html"`

of course i needed to call the electron file